# Two Images Side by Side With Hover Effect in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two images that I want to place side by side with hover effects. I've managed to get them side by side...but I'd like the images centered under the logo image.

CSS:

```
    a.btn1 {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width: 332px;
height: 85px;
cursor: pointer;
background-image: url(images/bttn_model.png);
text-indent: -9999em;
margin: 
}
a.btn1:hover {
background-image: url(images/bttn_model_over.png);
}

a.btn2{
display: inline-block;
width: 332px;
height: 85px;
cursor: pointer;
background-image: url(images/bttn_photographers.png);
text-indent: -9999em;
}
a.btn2:hover {
background-image: url(images/bttn_photographers_over.png);
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

<div align="center">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p><img src="images/logo.gif" width="618" height="85" /></p>
</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div align="center"><a href="#" class="btn1">Models</a>


<div align="center"><a href="#" class="btn2">Photographers</a>
</div>

</div>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap the 2 images in one div, so you can center that div with the following class

```
.centerDiv
{
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do what you want is following.

**HTML**

```
<div class="logo">
<img src="images/logo.gif" width="618" height="85" />
</div>
<div class="pictures">
    <a href="#" class="btn1">Models</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn2">Photographers</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.logo {
    text-align: center;
}
.pictures {
    text-align: center;
}
.pictures a {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 332px;
    height: 85px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
}
.btn1 {
    background-image: url('images/bttn_model.png');
}
.btn1:hover {
    background-image: url('images/bttn_model_over.png');
}

.btn2{
    background-image: url('images/bttn_photographers.png');
    /* next margin-left is to fix the space between */
    /* images that because of the inline-block */
    /* margin-left: -4px; */
}
.btn2:hover {
    background-image: url('images/bttn_photographers_over.png');
}
```

Using attributes like `align` is not nice practise nowdays. For this things there is solution in CSS.

Using `display: inline-block` and `float: left` is not needed in this case, while it is in one line already with `display`.

If you wanted to use `<p>&nbsp;</p>` instead of `margin` & `padding`, that put them back, but better practise is to stick with `margin` & `padding`